# Crafting a DNS Query Message in Python

Tags: python, tcp

I've been using Scapy to craft packets and test my network, but the programmer inside me is itching to know how to do this without Scapy.

For example, how do I craft a DNS Query using sockets (I assume it's sockets that would be used).

Thanks

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

Comment: @MarcB 's link is a great one to study.  Also, you could look at the internals of the Scapy source code to get some ideas.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnslib  , DNS uses UDP mostly.

Comment: Another fun way to go is sniffing with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), then sending the same data. That, accompanied by the RFC and a reference implementation, should provide for a good learning experience.

Comment: Barry, are you asking "how do I send packets" or "how to craft packets"?

Comment: If you aren't interested in sending the packets, or already know how to send them, then `sockets` won't be used. `sockets` is for sending packets.

Answer (score 2):

To open a UDP socket you'd use:

`s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP`

To send use:

`query = craft_dns_query() # you do this part
s.sendto(query,(socket.inet_aton("8.8.8.8",53))`

To receive the response use:
`response = s.recv(1024)`

You'll have to refer to documentation on DNS for actually crafting the messages and handling the responses.